# Как получить координаты для рисования в GDI+

Tags: c#, vb.net, gdi

Здраствуйте. Я использую метод FillClosedCurve для рисования фигур по точкам.

```
                Dim BM As New Bitmap(1000, 1000)
                Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BM)
                G.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
                G.FillClosedCurve(Brushes.Black, points_array)
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = BM
```

Для получения точек использую следующий принцип : ставлю картинку на задний фон формы и при нажатие на форму X и Y курсора добавляються в список точек.
**Мне нужно нарисовать скрипичный ключ , подскажите пожалуйста как удобнее можно получить список точек для построения , может как то их получить из png файла ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Я в цикле проверил все пиксели png файла, на альфа != 0 (у меня изображение без фона) , получил список непрозрачных пикселей (750 пар x,y) , и залил их в цикле чёрным цветом

```
    Dim gr As Graphics = PictureBox2.CreateGraphics
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image
    Dim spoints as as string

    /* получаем точки изображения из PictureBox1 */
    For i = 0 To bmp.Size.Height - 1
      For j = 0 To bmp.Size.Width - 1
        If bmp.GetPixel(j, i).A <> 0 Then
          gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, j, i, 1, 1)
          spoints &= j & " " & i & " "
        End If
      Next
    Next

    /* рисуем по точкам */
     spoints = spoints.trim()
     Dim gr As Graphics = PictureBox3.CreateGraphics
            Dim points_array() As String = spoints.Text.Split
            For i = 0 To points_array.Count - 2 Step 2
                gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, CSng(points_array(i)), CSng(points_array(i + 1)), 1, 1)
            Next
```